# finite field extensions: how to compute norm and trace

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, extension-field

I'm studying abstract algebra and I'm stuck in the topic of fields. I don't understand what the following definition

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $S$ be a commutative $R$-algebra, which is finitely generated and free as an $R$-module. The **trace** of $x \in S$ is the trace of the $R$-linear endomorphism $m_x : S \rightarrow S$, $m_x(y)=xy$, and is denoted by $\operatorname{tr}(x)$ or $\operatorname{tr}_{S / R} (x)$. The **norm** of $x \in S$ is $\det(m_x)$, and is denoted by $\operatorname N_{S/R}(x)$ or $\operatorname N(x)$.

The word "understand" above is perhaps not optimal, I mean it's just a definition, so there isn't really something to understand, but this definition confuses me. I know from linear algebra how to compute the trace and the determinant, this is not the problem, but I have no idea how to determine this $R$-linear endomorphism. Could someone explain this to me?

I have also found on the internet the following exercise: Let $K := \mathbb{Q}$ and $L := \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ and we consider the element $\alpha = \sqrt[3]{2} + 3 \in L$. Write down the matrix that represents multiplication by $\alpha$ with respect to some basis of L as $K$-vectorspace. Determine $\operatorname N_{L / K}(\alpha)$ and $\operatorname{tr}_{L/K}(\alpha)$.

I'm not really sure, if my attempt of solving this is right:
We can write down a basis of $L$ : $\{1, \sqrt[3]{2} , \sqrt[3]{2^2}\}$ and consider now multiplication by $\alpha$ :

$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\alpha * (x + y \sqrt[3]{2} + z \sqrt[3]{4}) &=& (\sqrt[3]{2} + 3)* (x + y \sqrt[3]{2} + z \sqrt[3]{4}) \\
&=& 3x + 3y\sqrt[3]{2} +3z\sqrt[3]{4} +x\sqrt[3]{2} +y\sqrt[3]{4} +z\sqrt[3]{4}\sqrt[3]{2} \\
&=& 3x + 3y\sqrt[3]{2} +3z\sqrt[3]{4} +x\sqrt[3]{2} +y\sqrt[3]{4} +2z \\
&=& 
\begin{pmatrix}
3x+2z & 3y+x & 3z+y \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 
\sqrt[3]{2} \\
\sqrt[3]{4} 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray*}
$

And now we can rewrite $\begin{pmatrix}
3x+2z \\ 3y+x \\ 3z+y 
\end{pmatrix}$ as

$
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 0 & 2 \\
1 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 3
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ 
y \\
z 
\end{pmatrix}
$

So the matrix which represents multiplication by $\alpha$ would look like
$
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 0 & 2 \\
1 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
$
And we would have $\operatorname{tr}_{L/K}(\alpha) = 9$ and $\operatorname N_{L/K}(\alpha) = 27 + 2=29 $

Is this correct? And can I solve every exercise of this form like this, I mean for the arbitrary $x \in S$ in the definition above.

Comment: That is correct. Some more worked examples are in http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/tracenorm.pdf.